# angularjs service error with mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, json, angularjs

I am new with angularjs and php

I want to get data from database,

but there is the error "Error: Unknown provider: $resourceProvider <- $resource <- Rdpservice"

CODE

```
angular.module('remoteApp')
 .factory('Rdpservice', function ($resource) {
return $resource('connect.php', {}, {
  query:  {method: 'GET'},
  get:    {method: 'GET'},
  remove: {method: 'DELETE'},
  edit:   {method: 'PUT'},
  add:    {method: 'POST'}
});
});


<?php
  $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password");
  if (mysqli_connect_errno())
 {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }

 $sql="CREATE DATABASE my_db";
 if (mysqli_query($con,$sql))
 {
   echo "Database my_db created successfully";
 }
 else
 {
   echo "Error creating database: " . mysqli_error($con);
 }

 $arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);
 echo json_encode($arr);
 mysqli_close($con);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me like you have not included the $resource service in your app. See here: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource

You need to "install" it, but including the script (found at the link above) and then requiring it in your module, like this: `angular.module('app', ['ngResource']);`